Gnosis Safe SDK to sign multisig on the backend
Is it possible to use Gnosis Safe's SDK to do multi signature collection to run a contract function? I would like to have several node independently verify something and then sign some proposal together, once it reaches n-of-k requirement it should mint tokens to an address or change a contract variable.

yes it should be possible by using Safe{Core} SDK Protocol Kit. There is a section in the documentation specifically about signing transactions.
Please let me know if it managed to help you do what you want.
Best, Louis

Thank you Louis, can you give us a code snippets using the EIP-712 signatures? I can't find a section where it can execute external smart contract's function. For example, we have a separate NFT contract and requires 2/3 owners' approve to execute mint function. Where can I submit transaction data  such as destination contract address, values, etc using your SDK?

Transaction data would be in the safeTransactionData object, in the very first lines of the section I mentioned. Then you can follow this guide to sign EIP-712 typed data: https://docs.safe.global/sdk/protocol-kit/guides/signatures/messages#create-the-message Hope it helps. Best, Louis

Thanks! so looking at the SDK, it stores all private keys in .env which I assume it's not safe to run 2/3 requirements. Is this the recommended way to run it? I think keeping each key in a separate server and execute transaction would be safer. Can we listen to the safe's event? what do you think about this approach?

Security will depend on how you manage secrets there. You can listen to (some) Safe events here: https://github.com/safe-global/safe-events-service
